# I have 9 JButtons in the ArrayList . But I am not able to change the Lable of the Buttons in any event,,,

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class One implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ArrayList<JButton> myB = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    Panel p = new Panel();
    Dimension d = new Dimension(20, 20);
    String s = "", s1 = "";
    JButton B = new JButton(), B1 = new JButton();

    public void addButtons()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            myB.add(new JButton());         //IMP
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        frame.getContentPane().add(p);
        for(JButton btn : myB)
        {
            btn.setPreferredSize(d);
            p.add(btn);        //IMP
        }
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 5));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void GamePlay()
    {
        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "HUMAN or COMPUTER");
        if(s.equals("HUMAN"))
        {
            for(JButton B1 : myB)
            {// advanced for loop
                B1.addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            s1 = "COMPUTER";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" action performed!!");
        B1.setText("X");
    }
}

public class Two
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        One a = new One();
        a.addButtons();
        a.display();
        a.GamePlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: did not really follow all code you wrote...try to call button.repaint() after you set the text

Comment: @Cris - wrong answer: if repaint seems to help, something is wrong with the code

Comment: if you are the kleopatra from swinglabs i am sure you are right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing B1 with the button in the list, and are calling setText in the wrong button. If you want to change the label of the clicked button, a quick fix would be.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(" action performed!!");
    B1 = (JButton)e.getSource();
    B1.setText("X");

}
```

You should have split the ActionListener into a differnt class to avoid confusion like this.
To apply the text for all button in the list, you can try something like this.

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{

    ArrayList<JButton> buttonList;
    public MyActionListener(ArrayList<JButton> a) {
        buttonList = a;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(JButton jb: buttonList) {
            jb.setText("X");
        }
    }
}


class One {
    MyActionListener buttonListener;
    ...
    public void GamePlay() {
    ...
        if(s.equals("HUMAN")) {
            buttonListener = new MyActionListener(myB);
            for(JButton B1 : myB) {
                B1.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        }
    ...
    }
```

}

Basically, create your own action listener contain the appropriate data to do what you want.

Comment: PLz do explain the below line in brief

Comment: And how can i split the actionlistener wen i want to apply that for all the buttons in the same ArrayList

Comment: Dikei , i am getting three dots on the button when i click on. Still cannot fix the problem ....

Comment: You're getting ... because the button size is not suitable. As kleopatra said, don't use setPreferredSize. I'll edit my code to show you how to apply the change to all button.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, @mKorbel is right: you don't see the button changing because it was never added to the ui. Plus, there are a handful of rules you didn't follow

- do not mix AWT with Swing components, use Swing consistently. They are easily recognizable by the *J* prefix
- do follow java naming conventions
- do choose narrative names (vs. B, s1, ...)
- do not call setPreferredSize
- do format the code to make it easily readable (vs too many white lines, inconsistent indentation)

Answer (score 2):

add `B1 = new JButton()` to `Panel p = new Panel();`